# Programming. AppleScript Editor. Greater Than, Less Than in If statements

Tags: applescript

Okay i want to check to see if the "user" has entered a number above 10, but i do not know where to put it or how to do it.

```
set volume 10
say "Hello and Welcome to Tyler's Spam Bot"

set amount to text returned of (display dialog "How many times?" default answer "More than 10")
repeat amount times
    tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
    if amount comes before 10 then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end if
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the value can be converted to an integer using a try/on error block.  If it can, continue, and ask if the number is greater than 10; if so, perform your action.

```
set received_integer to "False"

repeat while received_integer is not "True"
    set amount to text returned of (display dialog "How many times?" default answer "More than 10")

    try
        set amt_as_int to amount as integer
        if amt_as_int ≥ 10 then
            set received_integer to "True"
            repeat amt_as_int times
                tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
            end repeat
        end if
    end try

end repeat
```

Comment: This did not work, I need it to check to see if the number is smaller or greater than 10 and if it is smaller than 10 i need it to loop it back and re ask the question and if it is greater than 10 i need it to open the *amount* of Finder windows

Comment: It isn't looping around, i need to to re ask the question if the number is less than 10 and if not to open the *amount* of finder windows

Comment: Not exactly i need to to re-ask the question if the number is also less than 10, it will only ask the question if the number is not an integer

Comment: I tried it and it just opened the amount i put it, i put in one and instead of re-asking the question it just opened 1 window. Would you like me to send the script?

Comment: I'm sure im using the right version and your typo in the line "if amt_as_int ≥ 10 then" i changed it to "if amt_as_int ≤ 10 then" and if i put in 1 it will open 1 finder window

Comment: Never mind there was a formatting problem, i found it now, thanks for your help :)